# Structure/Design Pattern Solution

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, design-patterns

I am attempting to create a WordPress plugin and ran into a road block. I am creating a settings page that will need to be extended by child classes. The main class will look something like this.

```
class SettingsPage {

    // Properties

    // Methods

   public function metaboxes() {
       add_meta_box( //metabox params );
   }   

}
```

This class will handle the main settings page. I now want to be able to crete meta boxes from within several child classes. Basically extending/appending to the `metaboxes()` method.

```
class MetaBoxOne extends SettingsPage {

    public function metabox() {

         // add another metabox

    }

}
```

What would be the best solution for this problem? I've been staring at my code editor for a few hours trying to figure it out with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is inheritance the best route?

Comment: Does your programming language support virtual functions (in base class) that can be overriden (by child classes)?

Comment: I think traits is the way you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This design can use a bit more [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). Also having `IMetaBox` (interface) defined to ensure that your page classes will have functionality, that will allow you to adjust their content and behavior. So your settings page can look like this:

```
class SettingsPage {

    // Fields
    ICollection<IMetaBox> _metaBoxes;
    // Properties

    // Methods

   public function metaboxes() {
       add_meta_box( //metabox params );
   }   

}
```

All your

> that will need to be extended by child classes

will have the build-in functionality of a `ICollection<T>` that you'll need to manage the metaboxes, what is left to do is call a display method that'll iterate over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Maybe this article will helpful for you:
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-meta-boxes-on-custom-pages--wp-26843

---

Firstly, if you want to create a settings page for you plugin, I recommend you to use the built in Settings API. [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api--cms-624) teach you everything what you need to catch up the concept of this API.

Secondly, I think you couldn't use metaboxes on custom settings page, because the 'add_meta_boxes' hook only fires on edit post pages, see that in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference):

> Advanced Actions This section contains actions related to the queries
>   WordPress uses to figure out what posts to display, the WordPress
>   loop, activating plugins, and other fundamental-level WordPress code.
>
> add_meta_boxes  Runs when "edit post" page loads. (3.0+)

Finally: In other case if you have a main container, which contains child entities and you want to collect the child entities in your main container, I think you should follow the core Wordpress pattern, the callback action hooks. In your main collector you must define a custom action hook with:

```
do_action('your_plugin_main_collector_do_something', $param1, $param2, $param3, ...);
```

And your child entities should register themselves to the main container with this:

```
add_action('your_plugin_main_collector_do_something', 'my_entity_callback_function_name', $priority_default_10, $how_many_parameters_you_have_to_use);
```